# Assigning strings to a struct member (pointer) in C

Tags: c, string, struct, valgrind, assign

I need to be able to fill out my *my_s1* structure with data. I am passing it to a get_data() function that should do all the dirty work. The problem I have is the *b* member of my structure which is a pointer. I have no idea how to properly assign value pointed by *(char *) buff* to *b* without segmentation faults or valgrind errors.

For example:

1. Why does initial *p1->b="abc";* works fine, but if i try to *strcpy()* or assign through "*=*" operator an array to *p1->b* i get errors?
2. Does *s1 my_s1* allocate memory for *b* or should I somehow *malloc()* *p1->b* myself? But then again i need to free() it and assign a NULL pointer before returning from the function, which defeats the purpose (of having the function assigning data to structure), right?
3. With current code listed below I have "proper execution result" but I also get the following valgrind output errors (from what I understand, please correct me if I'm wrong, it seems as if *printf()* accesses not properly allocated memory - so it works in this case but it's rubbish) :

valgrind:

```
==1067== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==1067== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==1067== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1067== Command: ./if
==1067== Parent PID: 1059
==1067==
==1067== Invalid read of size 1
==1067==    at 0x4E7ADF9: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==1067==    by 0x4E83E38: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==1067==    by 0x4005EF: main (iface.c:10)
==1067==  Address 0x51f3040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 5 free'd
==1067==    at 0x4C294C4: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-
linux.so)
==1067==    by 0x40064D: get_data (ifacelib.c:17)
==1067==    by 0x4005D3: main (iface.c:8)
==1067==
==1067== Invalid read of size 1
==1067==    at 0x4EA9459: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.
so)
==1067==    by 0x4E7ADB1: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==1067==    by 0x4E83E38: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==1067==    by 0x4005EF: main (iface.c:10)
==1067==  Address 0x51f3043 is 3 bytes inside a block of size 5 free'd
==1067==    at 0x4C294C4: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-
linux.so)
==1067==    by 0x40064D: get_data (ifacelib.c:17)
==1067==    by 0x4005D3: main (iface.c:8)
==1067==
==1067== Invalid read of size 1
==1067==    at 0x4EA946C: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.
so)
==1067==    by 0x4E7ADB1: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==1067==    by 0x4E83E38: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==1067==    by 0x4005EF: main (iface.c:10)
==1067==  Address 0x51f3042 is 2 bytes inside a block of size 5 free'd
==1067==    at 0x4C294C4: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-
linux.so)
==1067==    by 0x40064D: get_data (ifacelib.c:17)
==1067==    by 0x4005D3: main (iface.c:8)
==1067==
==1067== Invalid read of size 4
==1067==    at 0x4EBBDDE: __GI_mempcpy (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==1067==    by 0x4EA939C: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.
so)
==1067==    by 0x4E7ADB1: vfprintf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==1067==    by 0x4E83E38: printf (in /usr/lib64/libc-2.17.so)
==1067==    by 0x4005EF: main (iface.c:10)
==1067==  Address 0x51f3040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 5 free'd
==1067==    at 0x4C294C4: free (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-
linux.so)
==1067==    by 0x40064D: get_data (ifacelib.c:17)
==1067==    by 0x4005D3: main (iface.c:8)
==1067==
==1067==
==1067== HEAP SUMMARY:
==1067==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==1067==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 5 bytes allocated
==1067==
==1067== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==1067==
==1067== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==1067== ERROR SUMMARY: 10 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Code in 3 files.

ifacelib.h:

```
#ifndef IFACELIB_H
#define IFACELIB_H

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    char * b;
} s1;

int get_data(s1 *);

#endif
```

ifacelib.c:

```
#include "ifacelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int get_data(s1 *p1)
{
    char *buff;
    p1->a=1;
    p1->b="abc";

    buff = (char *) malloc(strlen("test")*sizeof(char)+1);
    strcpy(buff, "test");

    p1->b = buff;

    free(buff);
    buff = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

iface.c:

```
#include "ifacelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    s1 my_s1;

    if ((get_data(&my_s1))==0)
    {
        printf("a= %d\tb= %s\n", my_s1.a, my_s1.b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help or just pointing in a right direction would be appreciated.

From *best practices* point of view, when working with structures should I be writing a function that fills out data in structure (works on a passed structure) and returns int to control successes/fails or should I be writing a function that returns a modified structure instead ?

This is my first post here, so please bear with me, my formatting mistakes, walls of text and my ignorance.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: I suspect that you have a basic misunderstanding about the difference between a pointer and the thing the pointer points at.  When you "assign a string" in C you're only assigning the pointer.  The actual character data doesn't move.

Comment: Why you immediately free after malloc? You can't access to p1->b after you free buffer too! p1->b is just a pointer point to a buffer, you can only free the buffer when you are sure that will no longer being used.

Comment: Thanks a lot @moeCake, I'm not freeing buff from within get_data() function anymore, instead in main() at the end im freeing (my_s1.b) and not getting memory leaks or valgrind errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing wrong, and just lucky to get correct result, in fact you are accessing memory that just being freed.
It's right that you have to malloc for the char* in struct(by the way, you can use strdup), but you need another destructor to free the struct when their job are done.
In your case, you need a function like free_s1 after the printf, rather than free in constructor function(get_data).

Answer (score 0):

This works in C, not so good in C++:

If you are going to malloc(), it may be better to malloc both your structure and the data area in one blow. Rather than having a pointer arrange a minimal data area at the end of the struct. When allocating the struct add additional bytes to allow for the data. You are then good to go. One free will release both struct and data.

Reworking fragments of your code to show the key idea I get the following. I leave compiling, debugging, even syntax checking, for the student.

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    char * b;
    char   data[1];    // data goes here. 
                       // structure MUST be malloced at run time WITH
                       //  extra storage for data.
} s1;
```

```
    s1   *p1;
    data = "test";
    data_len = strlen(data);       // additional bytes of storage
    p1 = malloc( data_len + sizeof( *p1 ) );  // allocate structure + data
    strcpy(s1->data, data );        // copy data to buffer

    ...
    free(p1);        // free storage
```